# VSTS Agent service can't get code coverage data when running as Local System

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

Short version:  Two builds, A and B, for the same commit, both running on our build server using the VSTS agent service

Build A:

- Agent running as Network Service
- Saves a .coverage file of 267kb, showing non-zero % code coverage
- Runs successfully, no errors, same test logs as build B

Build B:

- Agent running as Local System
- Saves a .coverage file of 1kb, showing 0% code coverage
- Runs successfully, no errors (except that a quality gate fails due to the 0% code coverage, but that's intentional), same test logs as build A

Extra info:
The VSTS Agent service normally ran on our build server as "Network Service", and all was well. Until we had to modify the agent service to run as "Local System" so it could access a cert in the "LocalMachine" store [which we need for Azure AD service auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#running-the-application-using-a-service-principal).  After that, it still claimed to do everything successfully except that the code coverage file is tiny and claims 0% code coverage, which is weird because the unit tests are certainly being run.  The logs from the two test tasks are exactly identical (except for things like timestamps and the build numbers), no helpful warnings or errors in there.

I'm sure it's probably not ideal to run the agent as Local System, but that account has more permissions than network service does, so I don't know how it could be a permission issue. I've probably just made a mistake in setting up something, but it seems like the only way out of this is to either

- give Network Service extra permissions (bad)
- regenerate / move the Azure AD service principal cert into the "CurrentUser" cert store for Network Service (feels bad but I'm not sure why)
- set up a new service account and resign ourselves to having permissions issues forevermore (ugh)

Can we somehow diagnose what exactly is going on with this test task without resorting to procmon? Or is there a better way to manage this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is rather annoying: I fixed it, but I don't know how.  While demonstrating it to a colleague, all I did was repeat my previous steps of rebooting the server and switching the agent service back and forth between the two accounts a couple of times, at which point the problem stopped being reproducible.  It seems this is one of those mysteriously vanishing problems that hides whenever you try too hard to investigate it. Hopefully it doesn't come back...